# QMutex ,wait here if a thread is in function

Tags: c++, qt, mutex, qmutex

I just want to implement the code like below.

```
QString Class1::getNonce()
{
    //if some thread is getting nonce wait here until it finishes the its own job.
    mutex.lock();
    QString nonce=QString("%1").arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t());
    mutex.unlock();
    return nonce;    
}
```

even I write with mutex different threads get same nonce. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Is mutex a static? Or are you using only once instance of Class1?

Comment: yes, it is in Class1 as QMutex mutex; and I just use mutex just this function.

Comment: Maybe because `QDateTime::currentDateTime` has only millisecond resolution?

Comment: that way,how can we ensure  every threads that call this function to get different and always bigger nonce than older nonce?

Comment: Do you have a c++11 compiler? c++11 has higher resolution time.

Comment: I have how can I use it?

Comment: @BMacit Different: possible if you append a random number to your string. Bigger: not possible without a shared counter or a clock with much higher resolution.

Comment: @Purrfection: it's worse than `QDateTime::currentDateTime()` having only millisecond resolution because `QDateTime::toTime_t()` has a resolution of only **one second**.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: it's a value that will be used in only a single communication or session - it can help prevent replay attacks by ensuring that each separate communication is unique, even if the payload is the same. It's similar idea to a salt or initialization vector and used for similar reasons. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Comment: @MichaelBurr: OK, thanks; weird name. ;-)

Comment: When I was helping yesterday I thought that nonce was a word in some other language that meant timestamp or similar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the use of a `QMutexLocker`.

```
Class1::Class1()
{
    m_mutex = new QMutex();

}

QString Class1::getNonce()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    QMutexLocker locker(m_mutex);
    counter++;
    return QString::number(counter);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use an atomic counter for your nonce:

```
QString Class1::getNonce()
{
    static std::atomic<unsigned long long> counter;
    return QString::number(counter++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all messages  I used a way like that

```
nonce=QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t()+7500;

......

QString Class1::getNonce()
{
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    mutex.lock();
    nonce+=timer.nsecsElapsed()/250;
    mutex.unlock();
    return QString("%1").arg(nonce);
}
```